# How to use AJAX in an MVC - php Blog? - adding comments dynamically

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller

I wrote a `posts.php` page which shows a certain post and its comments, giving the user the ability to *add a new comment* to this post dynamically.

I want to implement the *"submit_comment"* using Ajax, but I don't really know how to do it in MVC.

This is my Posts.php:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="Ajax/addComment.js"> </script> 
src="../views/Ajax/addComment.js"> </script> <title> Posts
(View)</title> </head>

<body> <div id="main"> <div class="container"> <?=$data['header'];?>

<div id="content">  
    <!-- Main Post -->
    <div class="content-background">
    <h2> <?=$data['title'];?></h2>
    <h4> <?=$data['date'];?> </h4>
    <p> <?=$data['content'];?></p>
    </div>

    <div id="form-content">
      <form name="commentForm" method="post">
      Enter your name:  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">&nbsp; <br />
      Enter your comment: </br> <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="10" rows="10"> </textarea> <br />

      <input value='Submit' type='button'  onclick='JavaScript:commentRequest2("<?=$data['id']?>")'
name='submit'>      


      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="commentArea">
        <?=include_once("comments_area.php");?>
    </div><!-- end commentArea -->


    </div>  </div> </div>


</body> </html>
```

This is My Posts_Controller.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * This file handles the retrieval and serving of posts posts
 */
class Posts_Controller
{
    /**
     * This template variable will hold the 'view' portion of our MVC for this 
     * controller
     */
    public $template = 'posts';

    /**
     * This is the default function that will be called by router.php
     * 
     * @param array $getVars the GET variables posted to index.php
     */
    public function main(array $getVars)
    {
        $postsModel = new Posts_Model;

            }
            else{
        //get the post
        $post = $postsModel->get_main_post("`id`='", $getVars['id'], "LIMIT", "1");
        //get the comments
        $comments = $postsModel->get_comments("`postID`='", $getVars['id']);
        //create a new view and pass it our template
        $header = new View_Model('header_template');
        $view = new View_Model($this->template);


        //assign post data to view
        $view->assign('header', $header->render(FALSE));
        $view->assign('title' , $post['title']);
        $view->assign('content' , $post['content']);
        $view->assign('date' , $post['date']);
        $view->assign('by' , $post['added_by']);
        $view->assign('id' , $post['id']);
        $view->assign('commentsArr' , $comments);
        $view->render();
            }
    }
}
```

And This is My Posts_Model.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Posts Model does the back-end heavy lifting for the Posts Controller
 */
class Posts_Model
{
    /**
     * Holds instance of database connection
     */
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new MysqlImproved_Driver;
    }

    /**
     * Fetches article based on supplied name
     * 
     * @param string $author
     * 
     * @return array $article
     */
    public function get_main_post($cond1, $var1, $cond2 ="", $var2 = "")
    {        
        //connect to database
        $this->db->connect();

        //sanitize data
        $var1 = $this->db->escape($var1);
        $var2 = $this->db->escape($var2);
        $cond = $cond1.$var1."'"; 
        $cond.= " ".$cond2." ".$var2;  

        //prepare query
        $this->db->prepare
        (
            "
            SELECT *  FROM `posts`
            WHERE $cond
            ;
            "
        );

        //execute query
        $this->db->query();

        $article = $this->db->fetch('array');

        return $article;
    }


    public function get_comments($cond1, $var1, $cond2 ="", $var2 = "")
    {        
        //connect to database
        $this->db->connect();

        //sanitize data
        $var1 = $this->db->escape($var1);
        $var2 = $this->db->escape($var2);
        $cond = $cond1.$var1."'"; 
        $cond.= " ".$cond2." ".$var2;  

        //prepare query
        $this->db->prepare
        (
            "
            SELECT *  FROM `comments`
            WHERE $cond
            ;
            "
        );

        //execute query
        $this->db->query();
        $resultArr[0] = 0;
        $i = 1;
        while( $result = $this->db->fetch('array')){
            $resultArr[$i] = $result;
            $i++;
        }
        $resultArr[0] = $i;

        return $resultArr;
    }

}
?>
```

Where Should I add the addComment.js? (V, M or C?)
And what should the addComment do? what URL/ function to call?

Any suggestions? Examples?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller create a function that will allow you to add javascript files to your views. Then call it in your controller. It will add the file path to an array, and just before the view is displayed, assign it to the template.

```
$view->addJavascript('/Ajax/addComment.js');
```

Or you can just use

```
$js_files[] = '/Ajax/addComment.js';
$view->assign('js_files', $js_files);
```

then in your view you can use

```
<?
   foreach($data['js_files'] as $file)
   {
       echo '<script type="application/javascript" src="'.$file.'"> </script>'
   }
?>
```

Not sure how your routing is structured in your application, but you would create a method similar to 
 main for the ajax functionality. if you mention more about how URLs route to Controller then I might bbe able to make a more educated suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>Before you even try to learn how to use MVC, you should learn how to write semantic HTML and unobtrusive JavaScript! Judging by `posts.php` files, you really have no clue what you are doing.</sub>
>
> <sub>I would recommend reading everything from [this page](http://microformats.org/wiki/posh). It will contains a lot of very good materials about HTML. Then watch [this lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs) and then watch everything on http://yuiblog.com/crockford/. Also i would advise you read [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html) book.</sub>

Are you using a home-made framework or is it some 3rd part product?

Anyway. You should start by making a non-AJAX method for adding comments. In your current setup it would most likely happen by adding `post_comment()` method in `Posts_Model`. And then creating a separate method in `Posts_Controller`,  for dealing with `POST` requests.

When that is done, you can start working on using AJAX to post new comments for the article. Your `'/views/Ajax/addComment.js'` file should be added in `posts.php` files (what you call "view", but it isn't). You should use absolute path for including that JS file.

The AJAX request should be executed through event handlers which is attached to `onsubmit` event for the `<form name="commentForm">`. You gather data from form's elements and create XHR request. To learn how to do it, read [this article](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php).

> <sub>That said, **your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.** Just because you use PDO/MySQLi it will not magically protect you. You actually need to know **how** to use it too. I would recommend reading [**this article**](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) (yes, it is for PDO, but the theory does not change). Especially [this section](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Running_Statements_With_Parameters). It should explain you how to properly use prepared statements and why it is important. For MySQLi equivalents you will have to read the [`MySQLi::bind_param()` manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).</sub>